# Is it possible to Spoof Another Machine's MAC Address on LAN?

Tags: spoofing, arp-spoofing, mac-address, mac-spoofing, arp

Is it possible to Spoof Another Machine's MAC Address on LAN?

I know we can spoof mac address of machine that we are currently on, using `macchanger` or `ifconfig wlan0 ether de:ad:be:ef:ca:fe`. But I want to make another host on LAN to pretend that it has certain mac address? Is it possible to do via anything? ARP?

And, A little about ARP: The router will broadcast a message "Who has the this MAC Address?" and the host replies. And in ARP Spoofing, Attacker intercepts and responds instead of actual host. Can we spoof this and let router know that another host(Host B) has diff. MAC Address?

PS: I don't have access to Host B, otherwise I could get on that machine and change its MAC.

Comment: What is your goal with that other machine? Do you want to intercept it's traffic?

Comment: if you just want to intercept traffic you could just do arp-spoofing

Comment: ARP spoofing only work best in network Hub. For network switch, the packet arrival will be intermittent, because the target machine ARP will also broadcast it location. Unless you are able to introduce a bridge before the target machine.

Comment: @nulldev, Martin: I don't want to intercept the traffic, I just want my router to know one of the machine on LAN has some specific Mac Address. Thats it.

Why I am doing this, Suppose in the same LAN, I have my Android device and its NOT rooted. And the LAN's Internet is configured for whitelisted MAC Addresses only. Since I know the password for wifi so I can be in on LAN from Android but can't use the Internet. So what I will do, I will send some packets to router (from my laptop) and spoof some valid Mac address as android's Mac Address so that I'll be able to use Internet on it.

Comment: short answer: no

Answer (score 2):

You cannot *change* the MAC address on the remote machine. The method you are looking for will keep answering the arp requests and fullfil them your supplied MAC. [Ettercap](https://ettercap.github.io/ettercap/) is the tool used. [Here](https://networklessons.com/switching/arp-poisoning/) is great description of how **arp poisoning** works. This does exactly what you are asking.

Comment: I have explored `arpspoof` and now trying this.

Comment: Please check as answered if this answers your question. Still new here and that would help.

Comment: Naah, It doesn't answer my question. I can only for my host: `ettercap -T -M arp /192.168.137.164/ /192.168.137.200/80` not for other hosts. Checking if ettercap doc has anything.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish by changing the MAC of a remote machine? I assumed you wanted to redirect traffic to your own machine.

Comment: Naah, I don't want to redirect the traffic to my machine. I don't wanna sniffing at all. I just wanna poison the arp cache of network for they think one machine has some mac address. Check my last comment on question.

Comment: I see. why not just try this Wifi Mac Changer for android? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wireless.macchanger&hl=en

Comment: Android has to be rooted in order to change Mac Address.

Comment: @vs4vijay why not intercept all of the other device's traffic thru your laptop? That way, all your router sees is your laptop's MAC... Nothing needs to be changed. It's not for sniffing, but to be the new gateway.

Comment: @schroeder Thanks for suggestion, It won't work in my case. If you want to help, We can hangout chat on my username at google's mailing service.